# Feeding multiple variables to the same univariate model, one by one at a time in SAS

Tags: macros, sas

I'm a new user to SAS. I'm trying to do multiple but simple exploratory univariate analysis using linear regression. I was hoping to find a more efficient way of writing SAS code.
For example, what I have in mind is the following:

```
proc reg data=test;
  model bmi= age;
  model bmi= calperday;
  model bmi= exercise;
  model bmi= (etc....);
run;
```

But I may have like 20 other predictive variables, and I'd rather not list them one by one.
PROC CORR would only give a correlation and P-value, but I actually want to see residual distribution as well. I know I can shorten it a bit if I use Macro like this:

```
%macro univar(var);
proc reg data=test;
  model bmi = &var;
run;
%mend univar;
%univar(age); %univar(calperday); %univar(etc.);
```

But this still requires me to list all variables one by one, but since they are all listed in continuous sequence in the data file, is there a better way?
Thanks!

Comment: You can look into call execute to process the variables and get the variable names from either proc contents, proc datasets or sashelp.vcolumn. There are many answers on here that demonstrate that method.

Answer (score 0):

Flip your data instead so you can use a BY group processing. This only works if you have all numeric variables. I like avoiding macro's as well.

```
*Flip data set;
data class;
set sashelp.class;
array vars(*) _numeric_;

do i=1 to dim(vars);
var_name=vname(vars(i));
value=vars(i);
output;
end;

keep weight var_name value;
run;

*Sort for by processing;
proc sort data=class;
by var_name;
run;

proc reg data=class;
by var_name;
where lower(var_name) ne 'weight';
model weight = value;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a macro solution, this may help. You can list all the variables from your main dataset through PROC CONTENT statement and copy paste the varible names to the macro.

```
%let var = age calperday exercise etc;
%macro univar;
%do i=1 %to %eval(%sysfunc(countc(&var., " "))+1);
   %let var1 = %scan(&var, &i);
   %put var1;
   proc reg data = test;
   model bmi = &var1.;
   run;
%end;
%mend;
```